# How to scale multiplayer online game backend?

Tags: architecture, url-routing, autoscaling

I am writing a game server. The game is a multiplayer turn based game, with initial matchmaking and/or private room creation. I plan my architecture to be as follows.

[image]

So initially, my users connect to the matchmaking service, generate a game, connect to each other, and listen for game start event via WebSocket from the matchmaking service. After that, whenever ready, the matchmaking service should redirect them to the corresponding game engine server, which will in its turn talk to clients via WebSocket. The reason I want them to be connected to the same server is to handle the WebSocket connections and data sync properly.

[image]

I know how I can do predefined routing, like based on a url key, or something like that, my question is:

How can I autoscale my game servers, and make them accessible through dynamic routing? Let's say a new game server spawns, it generates a routing key for himself, and notifies the matchmaking server about it. Or maybe the matchmaking server generates a new routing key for him, doesn't really matter. But how do I make my all consequent requests be routed properly? If I use Nginx as a proxy server for example, I will have to change configuration and restart Nginx, which is not what I want for my server, it should not have downtime when scaling up.

Comment: Does `matchamking` contain a typo or is it a different service than `matchmaking`?

Comment: Yes, I meant `matchmaking`

Comment: Do you also need to re-balance as well or just want to route some portion of the new users to game server n+1?

Comment: I don't think a rebalancing is needed in my scenario, I plan to distribute the load in a strict manner, and in case of a failover, I will just cut the game off for now.

Comment: Are you planning to use some off the shelf software component (like as you mentioned nginx) or are you willing to implement the dynamic routing by yourself as a part of the matchmaking service?

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume for a second that you are going to run 4 game servers on a single virtual machine (EC2 instance).

You would have to do some kind of static routing on each machine i.e. spin up the four game server processes and put an Nginx proxy in front with a static configuration that routes traffic to each of the game servers.

The critical observation here is that you don't scale one game server at a time you scale by adding EC2 instances which gives you +4 games servers each time a new instance starts.

All you need now is a registration mechanism so that the game servers can register with the matchmaking servers. Each game server would do a separate registration reporting:

- The public IP of the instance
- Their index (0-3) on that server.
- Their current state (Ready, Busy, Failed, ...)

You could implement this registration yourself or use a library designed for this purpose (For example Apache Zookeeper)

Finally I am expecting that you would put the game servers into an autoscaling group - you can probably control the size of the ASG from your matchmaking service - when it sees that the number of available game servers is low, it increases the group size.

---

To reduce the cluster size you need to:

- Make sure no games are running on a server (don't assign any new games to that server and wait for existing games to finish).
- Reduce the "min" size of the ASG so no new servers are started.
- Explicitly terminate the now empty server.